# RequestParam value converter

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, http-request-parameters

We are using Swagger to generate our API interfaces and model classes. However, Swagger generates the request parameters of our endpoints in a camelCase style instead of snake_case as it specified in our APIs.

For example, the code generated is:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/search/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Location> getLocation(@RequestParam(value = "locationId",required = true) locationID)
```

when it should be:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search/test",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Location> getLocation(@RequestParam(value = "location_id",required = true) locationID)
```

Is there any way to match programmatically (maybe using a HttpConverter) a request containing the param "location_id" with the method containing "locationId" without throwing a PathNotFound exception?
All our params are even Integer or String.

Comment: Hmm. A request interceptor might be able to do it.

Comment: Can I modify the URL of the incoming request before getting matched on the appropriate RequestMapper with an interceptor?

Comment: You might be able to map the parameters.

Comment: Also, how are you generating this code?

Comment: This code will be generated by using swagger-gencode, which creates the API interfaces. I then implement these interfaces in my RestControllers.